# Beamer bibliography color

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, color

I'm using the Boadilla theme with Beaver colortheme.
All the colored stuff are in dark red  as they should be, except for the bibliography item: they still use the structure color that is the classical blue.
I can get rid of this by manually changing the color, except from the bibliography number item, that is still in blue.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Alan included the image for you now. Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Answer (score 26):

You don't specify how you generate the bibliography. However if you use the standard `bibliography` environment from beamer, you can use beamer's color setting scheme. Simply add

```
\setbeamercolor{bibliography item}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamercolor*{bibliography entry title}{parent=palette primary}
```

(The `*` is necessary in the second command.)

Similarly, you can set the colors `bibliography entry author`, `bibliography entry location` and `bibliography entry note`. If you want to set the color explicitly instead of using the color from the theme, use `{fg=⟨color⟩}` instead of `{parent=...}`.

Comment: `bibliography entry author` works perfectly fine, but `bibliography entry journal` doesn't seem to work