# bibliography in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex, bibliographies

In Beamer, bibliography is displayed in the way that authors, title and journals are in three lines. Here is [an example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22545/beamer-bibliography-color).

Since I have many references, I am wondering, whether we can put them in one line to save some space? Another option is whether we can split the references into several slides?

Comment: How are you loading your bibliography? On my slides (where I use bibtex and `\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}`, there is no such splitting of lines.

Comment: Thanks Willie Wong,  I am using \bibliographystyle{apalike}, after changing to amsalpha, there is no such splitting of lines. :-)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

For splitting the references up into several slides, use the `allowframebreaks` option, as in:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
        \bibliography{../bib_files/jabrefmaster.bib}
\end{frame}
```

---

For the "three line splitting", this is because you either composed a bibliography list with the `\newblock` command built-in, or are using a `\bibliographystyle` that inserts the `\newblock` command. Your choices are to either drop the `\newblock`s (either edit them out or using a different style), or [modify how beamer handle's the command](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3215).

From the link, setting the following in the preamble should work:

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}
```

Comment: Thanks Willie Wong, your codes work perfectly on my system. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: You cannot use `\bibliography` outside the preamble.

Comment: @Bakuriu What in the world are you talking about? See the BibTeX [user guide](http://www.bibtex.org/Using/).

Comment: @WillieWong I have just tried to put your code and that's the error I get. Using `\printbibliography` works.

Comment: @Bakuriu: please ask a new question. In the question include a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), indicate how you compile the file, and give the exact error. (I am pretty sure the sentence "You cannot use \bibliography outside the preamble" is not the actual error shown to you.)

Comment: In particular, your mention of `\printbibliography` seems to indicate that you are using `biblatex` instead of `bibtex`? The answer above is based on the assumption that bibtex is used (see the comments on the OP).

Comment: @Bakuriu for biblatex, in the preamble load the bib file ``\makeatletter\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{\addbibresource{references.bib}}{\bibliography{references}}\makeatother`` and in the frame use ``[allowframebreaks]`` as stated in the answer to split the bibliography up into multiple frames. Then include using ``\printbibliography``. Works like a charm.