# Beamer references are zero-indexed

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}` for my bibliography style since I read in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30423/bibliography-in-beamer) that that particular bibliography style allows the references to be more compact, which was correct. In addition, after reading through [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124256/how-do-i-get-numbered-entries-in-a-beamer-bibliography), I used the workaround `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]}`. My problem is that, curiously, the bibliography entries appear to be zero-indexed, as shown in this screenshot: http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6733/irk9.png

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the bibliography style to `amsplain` fixed the problem and retained the desired reference structure.