# Divide references to multiple slides with Beamer+Bibtex

Tags: beamer, bibtex, presentations

I'm having problem. I'm creating presentation and I use Bibtex for references.
The problem is, the references slide don't split in two, when I have more references than fits into slide. It just disappears.

Eg. I cite 14 sources, in Bibliography I get only 8.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To let the references go over several slides, use `[allowframebreaks]` as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30428/283484).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend = biber,
            style = numeric,
            urldate = long, 
            maxcitenames = 2,
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{References}
    Here is an example of another reference\cite{a2}\cite{a3}\cite{a4}\cite{a5}\cite{a6}\cite{a7}\cite{a8}\cite{a9}\cite{a10}\cite{a11}\cite{a12}\cite{a13}\cite{a14}\cite{a15}\cite{a16}\cite{a17}\cite{a18}\cite{a19}.
    
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result of using frame breaks]