# Can \bibitem and BibTeX give the same output?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, bibtex, formatting

I am adding a slide to a beamer presentation containing some references and, since I only have three references, I was thinking about not creating an external `.bib` file this time.

However I realized that the graphical output of

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem ...
\bibitem ...
\end{thebibliography}
```

is a bit different than the one I am accustomed to using BibTeX. One example would be that, in place of the reference label, I get a small image.

So my question is: would it be possible to get an output such at the one shown in [Beamer bibliography color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22545/beamer-bibliography-color) using `\bibitem` only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]` does the trick (see section 10.6 of the manual). Don't forget to add `\newblock`s to your `\bibitem`s for correct line breaks and colors.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text \cite{A01}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A01} Author, A. \newblock ``Alpha''. \newblock 2001.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]